# WebApp Facebook Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova

When I start a local Webserver with my WebApp and I login to facebook it works, also when I connect from a mobile device via the browser.
But when I convert my WebApp to a Android Application via Cordova. I get the following message from facebook:

> Can't Load URL:  The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

But my question is, what should I enter in the App-Domain? (I already entered localhost)

Comment: after converting, are you browsing the app from an android device (not emulator)?

Comment: from the emulator, but there should be no difference?

Comment: hmm.. try adding 127.0.0.1 and your computer's local ip (something like 192.168.x.xx)

Comment: In Facebook App -> Settings -> App Domains I cant add 127.0.0.1, and the same for the local ip (172.18.xx.xx), another question

Comment: how is your login? are you using a cordova facebook plugin or just the js sdk? you need to add the android platform in the app settings.

Comment: I am just using the JS SDK and ok ill try

Comment: App domain does not accept IP addresses. For stuff that runs on the local machine, you need to use `localhost`.

Comment: this was my first thought but it doesn't work (If you read my start post)

Comment: Hey @MarkusG. any luck getting around this? I ran into the same issue and I am not able to find any answers out there!

Comment: I do not remember this issue anymore sorry. But now that I think about it and Facebook still is not allowing any IP's in there "App Domain" filed you can add a local dns (/etc/hosts) or add it in your router (if possible on yours) this could work.